# How is Spotify integrating with the default Clock application on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I just noticed that the default clock application (v6.0) on stock Android Pie (9.x) has a option to install Spotify under the sound settings for a specific alarm:

[image: Spotify install option]

A Play store installation dialog will be displayed that, once dismissed without installing, will leave behind a modified UI containing a Spotify fragment inside a Tab (presumably this would display songs to use):

[image: Spotify song selection fragment]

I have been unable to find out if this is some Intent based integration, that any other application out there might use, or if this is currently a hardcoded connection between 'Clock' and 'Spotify'. I am hoping it is the former. The only information I have been able to find about this integration is this [article](https://9to5google.com/2018/07/31/google-clock-spotify-integration-alarms/) (which is very dry on details, and does not answer if this is something that is generically open to other applications to use).

Any info on documentation for this behaviour would be appreciated.

Comment: very likely they manually implemented this. Can you imagine what a shitshow the clock app would become if everyone could just hook up their own stuff to it

Comment: Yes, very likely they did. And yes it would get crowded in there if anyone could add their application to the list without any oversight or control. There could however be ways to do it reasonably. For example; list up to 2 highest rated applications as menu items, then have a 'see all' item for the rest. Requiring that the application implement a ContentProvider serving up audio resources (for the list fragment) in a predefined way would also make sense.